# SQL pivot or self-join for this?

Tags: sql, join, pivot

I've a table, Events, which has 2 columns 
matter)
- entityId : string
- eventId : int

a presence of a row ("foo", 42) means that an event with id 42 happened on to the entity "foo".

what I want to do is figure out, from the table, which event id were NOT registered for which entities. E.g. the data:

"foo", 1

"foo", 2

"foo", 3

"bar", 1

"bar", 2

"baz", 3

should produce an answer of this kind:

....  | 1 | 2 | 3

foo|  y | y |y

bar|  y | y |n

baz|  n | n |y

I've looked around and saw references to pivots and joins floating around. Any suggestions on the best course of actions?
Thanks!

Comment: do you have a master table that holds all the events?and also post your attempt to solve this.

Comment: you mean all the event kinds, not instances of them occurring? I thought that would be of use, and I can get it (if only be selecting distinct or grouping by eventId from the source)

Comment: with out all events how would you know which of the entities is missing an event?

Comment: solutions that I attempted work on individual eventIds - "select.. where id == 1.." and then joining the result to the source table and selecting false or true if entity name is missing... but I have lots of different event ids

Comment: Generally, pivots are much easier at the display layer (report, form, page, etc.) since UI tools can be much more dynamic.  SQL is much more rigid (requires defined columns, etc.) and so pivoting (especially dynamically based on the data) is much trickier.

Comment: If you just want the events that were not registered, why is a pivot involved at all?  Why not just return a result set with each event and entity that are not registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I think this is what I need:

```
 SELECT
        entityId,
        COUNTIF(eventId == 1) AS event1_count,
        COUNTIF(event_id == 2) AS event2_count,
        COUNTIF(event_id == 3) AS event3_count,
        COUNTIF(event_id == 4) AS event4_count
    FROM data
    GROUP BY entityId;
```